# for loop c++ vs python

Tags: python-2.7

Could you please help me converting this c++ code into python:
I am trying to XOR the data

**C++ :**

```
void Encrypt(void data, Dword size)
{
    if(size > 0)
        for(DWORD i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
            ((LPBYTE)data)[i] ^= ((LPBYTE)data)[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean void* data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in python, you probably want to use the [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/bytearray.html) class:

```
def encrypt(data):
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        data[i] ^= data[i-1]      # for this to work, data has to be mutable

f = open('somefile.bin', 'rb')
buf = bytearray(f.read())
f.close()

encrypt(buf)
```

Note the comment, that you cannot pass a string object, because strings in python are immutable. `bytearray` on the other hand, is not.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, this seems to work but how come the output data size is doubled?

Comment: It works perfectly now. Appreciate your time and sharing your knowledge. You are both brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
def Encrypt(data, size):
    for i in range(size-1, 0, -1):
        data[i] = data[i] ^ data[i-1]
```

Though this isn't quite pythonic. You'd probably want to remove the explicit size argument and just use len(data)

Comment: Thanks Antimony, but for some reason i am getting this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'" Any thoughts?

Comment: That's because your running it on strings, for which xor doesn't make sense. You can convert it to numerical bytes by saying map(ord, s) where s is your string.